# can't import torch in vscode despite having anaconda interpreter and torch installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, torch, anaconda3

I have both python38,37 and anaconda installed, OS - win10,x64.

I could not install torch in py38,37 - but installed it in anaconda.

system env var 'Path' has:

- C:\python38\Scripts\
- C:\python38\
- C:\python37\Scripts\
- C:\python37\
- C:\anaconda3\
- C:\anaconda3\Scripts

In vscode, despite that i have selected interpreter as Python 3.8.3 base-conda

[image]

I still can't import torch. But when using jupyter notebook, I can import torch:

```
import torch
print(torch.__path__)

['C:\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\torch']
```

How to import torch in vs code and choose the right interpreter?

Answer (score 3):

When we import the module, we need to install the required module in the currently selected environment.([Python environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).)

I installed it in the base conda environment using the following statement:

> `conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch`

[image]

We need to pay attention to the selected kernel in Jupyter Notebook:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me: uninstall py37,38. Only have anaconda as a source of all python libs.
After import torch - you may get error from numpy lib:

```
from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

to fix it, add another system var:

```
C:\anaconda3\Library\bin
```

Actually maybe i did not need to delete other python versions.
but after all, importing torch worked in vs code:

```
from platform import python_version
print(python_version())
import torch
import torchvision
import numpy as np
print(torch.__path__)
print(np.__version__)
```

output:

```
3.8.3
['C:\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\torch']
1.18.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Install pytorch using the pip command shown below :

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113
```

Do this and then reload your vscode. If the error still exists, check if you install the module in your selected interpreter environment. This seemed to do the trick for me.